# SpriteKit- randomising spawn

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm trying to spawn an object randomly in the X-axis, but its only spawning in the center.

below is my quote relating to the spawn. What's missing?

//random func

```
func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}

func random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return random() * (max - min) + min
}
```

//spawn cat func

```
func spawnCat(){

    let randomXStart = random(min: gameArea.minX, max: gameArea.maxX)
    let randomXEnd  = random(min: gameArea.minX, max: gameArea.maxX)

    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart, y:self.size.height * 1.2)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXEnd, y: -self.size.height * 1)

    let cat = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "before right")
    cat.setScale(0.3)
    cat.position = startPoint
    cat.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(cat)

    let moveCat = SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration: 2)
    let deleteCat = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let catSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveCat, deleteCat])
    cat.run(catSequence)

}
```

Comment: add print statements, and print out what your random function outputs, and what the variable randomXStart's value is

Comment: a side note, use `arc4random_uniform` instead of your random method

Comment: What does the "gameArea" code look like ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use arc4random_uniform instead to get the results you want

```
func spawnCat(){



    let randomXStart = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(gameArea.maxX - gameArea.minX))) + CGFloat(gameArea.minX)
    let randomXEnd   = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(gameArea.maxX - gameArea.minX))) + CGFloat(gameArea.minX)
    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart, y:self.size.height * 1.2)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXEnd, y: -self.size.height * 1)

    let cat = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "before right")
    cat.setScale(0.3)
    cat.position = startPoint
    cat.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(cat)

    let moveCat = SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration: 2)
    let deleteCat = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let catSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveCat, deleteCat])
    cat.run(catSequence)

}
```

If you are getting 0 with this code then it means your gameArea width is 0

Comment: thanks man, i changed my code to
    func randomInRange(lo: Float, hi : Float) -> Float{
        return lo + Float(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(hi - lo + 1)))
    }
    
    func spawnCat(){
        
        // x coordinate between MinX (left) and MaxX (right):
        let randomX = randomInRange(lo: Float(self.frame.minX + 5), hi: Float(self.frame.maxX + 5))
        
        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(randomX), y: self.frame.height * 1.2)
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(randomX), y:self.frame.height * -0.5)
        let cat = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "before right")